# Angular material date-range-input for template driven forms

Tags: angular, angular-material, date-range

I am trying to implement a date-range-input for a template driven form but the official [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#date-range-picker-forms) doesn't say anything about template driven, only reactive forms.

I don't want to refactor the work to implement reactive forms because the original code is not mine.

Does anyone know if there is an official documentation for template driven forms? Thanks in advance